# Xamarin.Android : Gravity parameter in DrawerLayout.LayoutParams

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, drawerlayout

I'm trying to create a `DrawerLayout` programmatically using **Xamarin.Android**, but I faced a problem when trying to add the `ListView` which should be dragable form the left ..

Here is my code :

```
DrawerLayout myDrawerLayout = new DrawerLayout(this);
myDrawerLayout.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
SetContentView(myDrawerLayout);


FrameLayout myFrameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
myFrameLayout.LayoutParameters = new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
myFrameLayout.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Gray);
myDrawerLayout.AddView(myFrameLayout);


ListView myListView = new ListView(this);
myListView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Green);
myListView.LayoutParameters = new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams( width: 240,
                                                  height: DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
                                                  gravity: ????????
                                                           );
myDrawerLayout.AddView(myListView);
```

As you can notice.. I didn't know what to pass as a `gravity` parameter

The definition of the function in `DrawerLayout` class is like that :

```
public LayoutParams(int width, int height, int gravity);
```

So I have to pass `int` for the `gravity`, but how ??

I've tried the following :

```
myListView.LayoutParameters = new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams( width: 240, height: DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, gravity: Gravity.LEFT);
```

It gives me error:

> 'Gravity' does not contain a definition for 'LEFT'

Also tried :

```
myListView.LayoutParameters = new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams( width: 240, height: DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, gravity: GravityFlags.Left);
```

but gives me an error:

> cannot convert from 'Android.Views.GravityFlags' to 'int'

Hope you have an idea about the solution .. and thanks in advance

Comment: `keeps giving me error` what error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to cast the flag to int like

```
new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(240, DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, (int)(GravityFlags.Start | GravityFlags.Left)).
```

Comment: thanks, it's working great .. but what's the benefit of the | sign means here ??

Comment: `|` is a bitwise or. This is the way how you set multiple flags.

Comment: it just need to be `MatchParent` instead of `WrapContent` .. it was a mistake in my code also

Answer (score 0):

Since DrawerLayout is a Class from the Support Packages you can use GravityCompat:

```
   myListView.LayoutParameters = new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(width: 240,
                         height: DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, 
                         gravity: GravityCompat.Start);
```

Comment: `GravityCompat` provides only `Start` .. there is no `right`, `left` or `center` .. Guess that Sven answer is a little bit more useful .. Thanks for your effort

Comment: Start is basically the same as left.