# How to create a NavigationView programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin.android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to create a Navigation Drawer programmatically, it all works bar the Navigation View which covers the screen and blocks the other content. I have removed the Navigation View and the content displays correctly again.

```
private View SetupNavigationView() {
    fullLayout = new DrawerLayout(this);
    fullLayout.LayoutParameters = new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
    fullLayout.SetFitsSystemWindows(true);
    fullLayout.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Black);

    LinearLayout relLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    relLayout.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
    relLayout.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
    relLayout.WeightSum = 100;

    toolbar = new SupportToolbar(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams tParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent,0, 10);
    toolbar.LayoutParameters = tParams;
    toolbar.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Gray);
    toolbar.SetMinimumHeight(50);

    activityContainer = new FrameLayout(this);   
    activityContainer.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent,0,90);
    relLayout.AddView(toolbar);
    relLayout.AddView(activityContainer);    
    fullLayout.AddView(relLayout);

    navigationView = new NavigationView(this);
    DrawerLayout.LayoutParams navLayout = new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent,                                      DrawerLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
    navigationView.LayoutParameters = navLayout;
    navigationView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Blue);
    navigationView.SetFitsSystemWindows(true);
    //navLayout.Gravity = GravityFlags.Start; 
    //Had to comment this out as DrawerLayout.LayoutParams does not implement Layout Gravity.

    fullLayout.AddView(navigationView);
    return fullLayout;
}
```

I originally tried using `LinearLayout.LayourParams` for the Navigation View but that still didn't make a difference. I have spent a fair amount of time working on this so this is the final piece i need to get working. Thank you for any help or suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "DrawerLayout.LayoutParams does not implement Layout Gravity", but that is what you need to indicate that the `NavigationView` is a drawer. Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39012568/xamarin-android-gravity-parameter-in-drawerlayout-layoutparams) for an example of creating the necessary `LayoutParams`.

Comment: @MikeM. Setting the gravity as shown in the link you sent me worked perfectly. Thank you very much. Do you want to add it as the answer and i will accept. Thank you again

Comment: It's cool. You can just select the "That solved my problem!" button (or whatever it says) to close out your question. Thanks, though. Glad you got it working. Cheers!